# How to auto-create different contents for the same components in my astro page?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

When I provided the contents in different md files called post1 and post2, I would like to add each content to my components called Service. When I do it like I describe below, I am having an error on my component page says title is not defined. How can I add those content automatically?

my page file:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import { getCollection } from "astro:content";
const allPosts = await getCollection("posts");
import Service from "../components/Service.astro";
---

<Layout title="Serwis">
    <ul>
        {
             allPosts.map((post, index) => (
                <Service key={index} title={post.title} price={post.price} description={post.description}/>
            ))
          }
    </ul>
</Layout>
```

post1 md file:

```
---
title: Konserwacja Klimatyzatora    
description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tincidunt, lacus sit amet ullamcorper feugiat, neque augue vulputate dui, vel condimentum justo nunc a ipsum.
price: Już od ...PLN
---
```

my component:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
---

<Layout title="Service">
    <div>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{price}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{description}</p>
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Service.astro` component should look for example like:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';

const { title, price, description } = Astro.props
---

<Layout title="Service">
    <div>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{price}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{description}</p>
</Layout>
```

Or instead of having three different props (title, price, description) you could have just one (post), and call it like `<Service post={post} />`.

Answer (score 1):

The frontmatter for your collection entries can be accessed using `post.data.title` instead of `post.title`

[Collection Entry Reference](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#collection-entry-type)